# IOS Charts positioning of gridlines

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am struggling to find out how to set gridlines on my chart to specific points on the x axis and to centre labels on the lines corresponding to the time of day.  I have a simple chart, the data represents a day with about 280 data points (one for every 5 minute period).  I want to show gridlines at times of the day equal to 03:00, 06:00, 12:00, 15:00, 18:00 and 21:00 and show the corresponding labels centred below the gridlines.  I have have also tried LimitLines, which works for placing the vertical lines at the correct points, but there does not seem to be the ability to align the time labels with the centre of the limit lines.

I know this can be done because I have seen screenshots on-line showing time labels centred on gridlines (or limitlines) for specific periods on the day, but I've spent hours looking for how to do this an I'm drawing a blank.

My code below (note the commented out failed attempt to get limitlines to work).

```
let tideHeights = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries)
    tideHeights.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    tideHeights.colors = [NSUIColor.black]

    //let timings = ["00:00", "03:00", "06:00", "12:00", "15:00", "18:00", "21:00"]

    let data = LineChartData(dataSet: tideHeights)

    lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: dataPoints)

    //lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    //let gridLine = values.count / timings.count
    //var xPos = 0

    //for label in timings {
        //let limitLine = ChartLimitLine(limit: Double(xPos), label: label)
        //limitLine.labelPosition = .bottomLeft
        //limitLine.lineWidth = 0.5
        //limitLine.lineColor = .black
        //limitLine.valueTextColor = .black
        //lineChartView.xAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine)
        //xPos += gridLine

    //}

    lineChartView.xAxis.labelCount = 7
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

    lineChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
    lineChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
    lineChartView.legend.enabled = false
    lineChartView.data = data
```

The output is below, the gridlines are at system set positions, how can I control where they are placed?
[image: iPhone screenshot]

Update:

After applying the very helpful suggestion by Stephan Schlecht, I am still getting strange results.  With `lineChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(9, force: true)` I get:

[image]

and with `lineChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(4, force: true)` I get:

[image]

It seems for some reason that the 1st gridline after the Axis is ignored.

Code is:

```
lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: dataPoints)

    let marker = ChartMarker()
    marker.setMinuteInterval(interval: 5)
    marker.chartView = lineChartView
    lineChartView.marker = marker

    lineChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(4, force: true)
    lineChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    lineChartView.leftAxis.labelPosition = .insideChart
    lineChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    lineChartView.legend.enabled = false

    lineChartView.data = data
    lineChartView.data?.highlightEnabled = true
```

Update 2

To reproduce, I have the following class which creates the data (btw, it is a stub class, eventually it will contain a paid api, so for now I generate the data for test purposes:

```
class TideHeights {
var tideHeights = [Double]()
var tideTimes = [Date]()
var strTimes = [String]()
var intervalMins = 5

init (intervalMins: Int) {
    self.intervalMins = intervalMins
    let slots = 24 * 60.0 / Double(intervalMins)
    let seconds = 24 * 60 * 60.0 / slots
    let radians = 2 * Double.pi / slots
    let endDate = Date().endOfDay

    var date = Date().startOfDay
    var radianOffset = 0.0


    repeat {
        tideHeights.append(sin(radianOffset) + 1)
        tideTimes.append(date)

        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        strTimes.append(timeFormatter.string(from: date))

        date = date.advanced(by: seconds)
        radianOffset += radians

    } while date <= endDate   
}
```

}

this class is instantiated and used to draw the graph in the following two functions in ViewController.

```
func drawChart() -> Void {

    let tideData = TideHeights(intervalMins: 5)

    lineChartView.dragEnabled = true
    lineChartView.setScaleEnabled(false)
    lineChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false

    setChartValues(dataPoints: tideData.strTimes, values: tideData.tideHeights)

}

func setChartValues(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) -> Void {

    //initialise and load array of chart data entries for drawing
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    for i in 0..<values.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let tideHeights = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries)
    tideHeights.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    tideHeights.colors = [NSUIColor.black]

    let gradientColors = [ChartColorTemplates.colorFromString("#72E700").cgColor,
                              ChartColorTemplates.colorFromString("#724BEB").cgColor]

    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: gradientColors as CFArray, locations: nil)!

    tideHeights.fillAlpha = 0.7
    tideHeights.fill = Fill(linearGradient: gradient, angle: 90)
    tideHeights.drawFilledEnabled = true

    let data = LineChartData(dataSet: tideHeights)

    lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: dataPoints)

    let marker = ChartMarker()
    marker.setMinuteInterval(interval: 5)
    marker.chartView = lineChartView
    lineChartView.marker = marker

    lineChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(4, force: true)
    lineChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    lineChartView.leftAxis.labelPosition = .insideChart
    lineChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    lineChartView.legend.enabled = false

    lineChartView.data = data
    lineChartView.data?.highlightEnabled = true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> **setLabelCount(int count, boolean force):** Sets the number of labels for
>   the y-axis. Be aware that this number is not fixed (if force == false)
>   and can only be approximated. If force is enabled (true), then the
>   exact specified label-count is drawn – this can lead to uneven numbers
>   on the axis.

see https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/axis-general/

Remark: although the y-axis is mentioned in the documentation of the function, it can actually be applied to both axes.

So instead of

```
lineChartView.xAxis.labelCount = 7
```

use

```
lineChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(9, force: true)
```

Note: you need 9 label counts not 7.

**Test**

If one combines a sine wave of 288 points with your code above

```
for i in 0...288 {
    let val = sin(Double(i) * 2.0 * Double.pi / 288.0) + 1
    dataEntries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val))
}
```

and forces the label count = 9 as shown, then it looks like this:

[image: forced label count screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Stephan, a good reference to documentation (which I have struggled to find so far).  I have applied your suggested changes, which should work, however they give me strange results.  I have updated my original question with the results above.

Comment: @JimBurke I guess the number of dataPoints that you supply to xAxis.valueFormatter does not match the number of entries in the LineChartData that you supply to lineChartView.data. It must be equal. Then setLabelCount with forced=true works.

Comment: Alternative solution would be to implement IAxisValueFormatter interface and set it to xAxis.valueFormatter. In the stringForValue method you could e.g. calculate the time string based on x value and a start date. This would also work.

Comment: That the number of dataPoints is not equal to the number of entries in LineChartData seems to be the most likely cause. But since you do not show how the dataPoints are determined, this is difficult to say. If this doesn't solve you issue, maybe you could update the question and add a minimally reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I checked and the datapoint and value counts are equal.  I have updated the above question with minimally reproducible example.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting: shows correct labelling here when using forced label. I'm using Charts version 3.4.0. Do you use a different version? My version has a IMarker protocol, but no ChartMarker, so only change was to remove ChartMarker lines. I can upload and share my Xcode test project if that's helpful.

Comment: yes, 3.4.0 (shown in Charts-Info.plist).  I will see if I can add IMarker and remove ChartMarker and see if that helps.  And, please if you could upload test project and I will see if it runs same on my machine.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I am curious: https://www.software7.biz/iertzzlmaksjdfkjlkj/chartdemo.tgz - screenshot: https://www.software7.biz/iertzzlmaksjdfkjlkj/screenshot.png - I use cocoapods in my test project, so you need to open the workspace .xcworkspace (.xcodeproj will not work).

Comment: Thanks Stephan.  Really scratching my head now.  Your code works fine and display's as I want to see it.  My code (I also use cocoapods) is identical and continues to display strangely!

Comment: Interesting. You could upload the project somewhere so I could take a look at it, if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate that - and, if you could do me a great service and give me a critique of my code while you are at it!.  I am self learning!

Comment: I guess it make sense to continue the discussion in chat - since it's not really comments about the answer - I missed unfortunately the  dialog to move to chat, so I created this room here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/209767/ios-charts-positioning-of-gridlines. Let's continue there.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht Sir can we draw the verticle lines between every box line we  can. see on the Scale

Answer (score 0):

Stephan was correct in his answer to this question.  To force gridlines and alignment, use `setLabelCount(x, force: true)` the additional complexity related to my specific project and the data contained in the labels.